# How to create a token that is minted upon purchase?

Tags: tokens, erc-20

I want to test a token system that goes like this:
Deposit _token, receive x amount of token0. But I hope for token0 to be minted upon deposit.

Using openzepellin standards what do I need to do for this to work?

```
// contracts/SimpleToken.sol
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.2;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

/**
 * @title SimpleToken
 * @dev Very simple ERC20 Token example, where all tokens are pre-assigned to the creator.
 * Note they can later distribute these tokens as they wish using `transfer` and other
 * `ERC20` functions.
 * Based on https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v2.5.1/contracts/examples/SimpleToken.sol
 */
contract SimpleToken is ERC20 {
    /**
     * @dev Constructor that gives msg.sender all of existing tokens.
     */
    constructor(
        string memory name,
        string memory symbol,
        uint256 initialSupply
    ) public ERC20(name, symbol) {
        _mint(msg.sender, initialSupply);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the contract that handles the deposit to be the owner of your token contract, and you need to call `mint` in your `deposit` function. Something like this would work :

```
IERC20 depositToken = IERC20(depositTokenAddress)
IERC20 buyToken = IERC20(buyTokenAddress)

function deposit(uint256 amount) public {
    depositToken.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
    uint256 amountBought = // your math here, this should be pretty straightforward. 
    buyToken.mint(msg.sender, amountBought) // You need to have a mint function in your token contract. 
}
```